# Python 3, ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPClient'

Tags: python, python-3.x, httpclient

I'm fairly new to python am interested in making a script for discord. After installing everything I was supposed to and plugging in the example code, I am getting errors.

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    counter = 0
    channel = discord.Object(id='channel_id_here')
    while not client.is_closed:
        counter += 1
        await client.send_message(channel, counter)
        await asyncio.sleep(60) # task runs every 60 seconds

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
client.run('token')
```

Error:

```
F:\Python\python.exe "F:/Python Projects/DiscordPlugin1.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Python Projects/DiscordPlugin1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
  File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .client import Client, AppInfo, ChannelPermissions
  File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .http import HTTPClient
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPClient'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If anyone could at least point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you executed it with python3? `python --version`

Comment: Yes, after running that check cmd says I am running Python 3.5.2.

Comment: Also some information that may help, the github page for discord.py (https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) says to use 'python3 -m pip install -U discord.py' However, python3 was not recognized as a command, so instead i used 'python -m pip install -U discord.py' to install it.

Comment: I have discovered that I am using a library called aiohttp which is supposed to be a replacement for HTTPClient and HTTPServer. Maybe I need to somehow get python to use aiohttp instead of HTTPClient?

Comment: Edit file F:\Python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py  put '#' in front of 'import HTTPClient' replace with 'import httplib'

Answer (score 0):

It seems that file `discord/http.py` does not contain definition of `HTTPClient`. Can you please provide contents of this file?

Comment: discord/http.py does not contain any code, it is an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

Installing a different version of discord.py seemed to work.

pip install -U https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/archive/master.zip#egg=discord.py[voice]

This was the version I used.